# Xamarin.Forms on Desktop - Document based Application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, desktop-application

Is it possible to create document based applications with Xamarin.Forms on Desktop (Mac/Windows)?

Xamarin.Forms.Application seems to be single document/window application.

thx.

Comment: You can open more windows? Can you be a little more specific

Comment: yes this is the question. how can i open multiple window instances and bind to a Xamarin.Forms.Page

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET has not a framework for Mac and Windows capable Window based frameworks in these days and there is no plan to support as well. Though, there is WebBrowser based application for it.